# Android screen resoulution problem

Tags: android, bitmap, resolution

I'm writing a game for Android and can now test it on a second device, the Nexus 1. The game uses fix pixel-values, just using bigger cutouts of the background for high-res devices. So I thought there would be no problems. Somehow, however, the nexus 1 is making a specific image bigger than it should be (261*66 instead of 174*44). The picture itself as a resource is 174*44, so it's being stretched. Why? What can I do against it?

Edit:

```
    Spritesheet = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,
        R.drawable.bird_spritesheet);
```

Is the used code.

Edit 2:

Is there no way to tell the software to just use the size the picture is? I don't want to bloat my software by adding multiple pictures (/drawable-hdpi/ answer).

The pictures are supposed to be smaller on bigger screens.

Comment: "Is there no way to tell the software to just use the size the picture is?" - It is displaying it at the size that it "thinks it is" but since it is in plain drawable, or drawable-mdpi. It is giving it a region of the screen that is set to a lower resolution, which leads to a larger than expected picture. You could manually set the width and height lower I think. But preferred solution AFAIK is to put it into the correct drawable folder.

Comment: Ok it worked for the last release, why wont it work now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what drawables folder to you have the picture in? If you put a copy of it in drawables-hdpi I think it will show up real size. It is really better to set things up in such as way that the final size in pixels it ends up is unimportant. Using pixels values is going to ensure that your app looks wrong on at least some of the screen sizes out there.

Comment: Correct, so is the other answer to this question. But what I was looking for was something else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330097/how-do-you-tell-android-not-to-scale-images

Answer (score 0):

Because Android runs on multiple screen sizes and you use device independent pixels (DIPs), images get scaled to ensure they look the same on all devices. To avoid this, you can provide alternative resources for high density screens (in your case) and for low density screens.

[More info about screens here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)